# Adding group permissions with sudoers with NOPASSWD still prompting for password

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, sudo, sudoers

Fedora 20, clean install. I added the following lines to my sudoers file with visudo:

> %power  ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown

I then created group "power" and added my account to this group. Rebooted, confirmed that I was in the group with the "groups" command.

However, when I type "sudo shutdown" I am still prompted for a password.

---

### Update:

I previously had my permissions group %power located in the sudoers file below root:

> root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

but above %wheel:

> %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

It works now if I move it to below %wheel. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` processes the lines in order.

The `ALL` in the `%wheel` line applies to `sudo /sbin/shutdown`, and isn't tagged with `NOPASSWD`. Any user who is in both the `wheel` and `power` group would have to enter their password when running `sudo /sbin/shutdown`; users just in the `power` group would not.